# What causes NullPointerException in this code?

Tags: android

What causes NullPointerException in this code..........?
and gives   unfortunately has stopped

```
ArrayAdapter spinneradapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.Repeating, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinneradapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                TextView myText = (TextView) view;
                Toast.makeText(CreateActivity.this,
                        "you selected" + myText.getText(), 1000).show();

        }
```

Comment: If you have a NPE, you have a stack trace, right?  That'd tell you exactly where it was triggered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i think the problem is that this spinner is defined in xml that differ from the xml of activity where it is (it is defined in  activity that connect with xml that differ from spinner xml) ,, could this Cause null pointer exception??
and how to connect spinner view with it's xml ??

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with this line.I cant pin point anything without the logs but give this a shot

```
TextView myText = (TextView) view;
```

is not referencing any layout element

Try

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);//where view is your textview
```

Comment: `view` is referenced in the callback.